# Find all occurences by pattern and replace quotes within it in Python

Tags: python, regex

I want to replace quotes `"` with `\"` inside quotes in my long String. So, I came up with idea to find it by pattern and then replace those quotes. But what I'm missing is probably wrong pattern or wrong method usage:

```
string = re.sub(r"\"(.*)\"",  r"\1", string).re.replace("\"", "\\\"")
```

Unfortunately it still replaces all quotes instead of those inside.

This is what I want to achieve, replace this
`"text example.. something + "hello" + foo"`
to this: 
`"text example.. something + \"hello\" + foo"`

Note, that this can occur many times in my long string. Thanks for any kind of advice! :)

**@EDIT**
I think it is better to add the exact example of my string (my string looks similar to `JSON`:

`"data": "fun () { return this.value * 20 + "x"; }"`

now I want to remove quotes from *x* like this:

`"data": "fun () { return this.value * 20 + \"x\"; }"`

Comment: Please leave a comment before down voting so I can improve my question in any way

Answer (score 0):

Try using negative lookaround :

```
(?<!^)\"(?!$)
```

See [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/qj9yHC/2).

This won't match the first and the last quotes, only those inside the string.

Comment: If you switch the flavour to Python, this returns an error on your link

Comment: @Vinny That is regex101 problem, not this pattern. However, the pattern only relies on the fact that `"`s that should not be escaped are at the start and end of the string, which is not always true to life. There may be whitespaces before or after them.

Comment: Edited, needed to escape the quote.

Comment: should I use only `re.sub()` method?

Comment: @Paul-Etienne Still, it will escape the first and last `"`  if preceded/followed with leading/trailing whitespace.

Comment: What if he uses a trim() function before ?

Comment: The IDE complaining about empty group for `(?<!^)`

Comment: after `^` addition it replaces all occurences of `"`